# React Native camera Tap to foucs not working in android

Tags: react-native, android-camera

**Tap-to-focus** with react-native-camera is not working on Android.

Already tried with `defaultOnFocusComponent={ true }` and add this to `AndroidManifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

But still i am unable to tap and set focus on `React Native Camera`